# ABS using both ABS magnetic ring + ABS toothed ring?

Tags: abs, axle, bearing

My SUV a Mazda CX9 2008 needs a rear bearing replacement, so picked up a rather budget wheel hub as the vehicle is close to retirement anyway.

The vehicle has ABS, and the rear axle has the ABS toothed ring on it like in this picture:

[image]

The wheel bearing hubs come in two forms: 1) with ABS magnetic ring and 2) no ABS.

The hub I pickup does not have the magnetic ring; did not think about it at the time of order. Now I am double guessing myself why I would need both magnetic + toothed rings? Surely if there is a speed sensor over a toothed ring that is enough right? Don't want to end up with ABS light on, and one wheel not releasing.

Are both magnetic ring and teeth needed?

Comment: If it needed it to begin with, it probably still needs it, don't you think?

Comment: Perhaps. I looked up the circuit for ABS, wiring diagram only shows 4 censors over the steps. No other sensors. If sensor points to steps, how can it read magnetic? Getting the feeling that - lets say 2018 CX-9 no longer has steps but has magnetic, but bearing size is the same, so ABS version will mechanically fit along with the no-ABS version. I may simply be buying a magnetic bearing that is not needed. If I could prove that some vehicles require both, then sold. I can't find this info, it always seems one or the other.

Comment: A driving factor is price. The magnetic version is 6x times more expensive - literally, not hyperbole. If I can save 300 bucks on a vehicle with well over 300km on it and ready to retire by next year, I definitely want to

Comment: If you want the abs to work then you need a new hub with the toothed ring. Fitting the magnetic one will not work with the rest of the system. Also, does the abs need to be working or "error free" to pass inspection?

Comment: @mike neither of the hubs have a toothed ring, the toothed ring is attached to the axle. No inspections or anything required. Cheers